libTooling - AST matcher last unitialized function variable
I am writing a tool to rewrite C files.  Some of these files are very old legacy files that declare uninitialized local variables at the start of each function. I need to develop an AST matcher & corresponding MatchCallback to find the position immediately following the last uninitialized variable in a function - where I can place some special code.
As a plus, for more up to date C code with mixes of both initialized and uninitialized variables at the start of a functionDecl, I would like to find the position immediately following the opening '{' of the functinon.
So far I have identified a potential clang-query type matcher that can find the uninitialized local variables following a function decl.  This should be a good starting point to finding a solution.
Here is the Entry handler I use to process the MatchCallback. I need help in the run method to find the position where I can add my own code.
class EntryHandler : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
public:
    explicit EntryHandler(Rewriter& rewriter)
        : mRewriter(rewriter)
    {}

    //! This is where the magic happens.
    void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &result) override {
        if (const auto* FD = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<FunctionDecl>("func")) {
            // This will be called for each function.
            const auto functionName = FD->getNameInfo().getAsString();
            const auto VD = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<VarDecl>("uninitVar");
            const auto uninitializedVariableName = VD->getNameAsString();
            // I NEED HELP HERE
            // Retrieve all uninitialized variables in the function.
            //for (const auto& next : result.Nodes.getMap()) {
            //    const auto key = next.first;
            //}
            //const auto next = result.Nodes.getNodeAs("uninitVar");

            //for (const auto *VD : Vars) {
            //    // This will be called for each variable declaration in the function.
            //    std::cout << "  Found variable: " << VD->getNameAsString() << "\n";
            //}
        }
    }
private:
    Rewriter& mRewriter;
};


// ASTConsumer implementation reads AST produced by the Clang parser.
// Here we register our instrumentation matchers and run them against the AST.
class MyASTConsumer : public ASTConsumer {
public:
    MyASTConsumer(Rewriter& r)
    : mEntryHandler(r) {
        // Add for finding function entry declarations.
        mMatcher.addMatcher(traverse(TK_IgnoreUnlessSpelledInSource,
            functionDecl(isExpansionInMainFile(), 
                forEachDescendant(varDecl(unless(
                    hasInitializer(anything())), 
                    hasLocalStorage()).bind("uninitVar")))
                    .bind("func")), &mEntryHandler);

    }

    void HandleTranslationUnit(ASTContext& context) override {
        // Run the matchers when we have the whole TU parsed.
        mMatcher.matchAST(context);
    }

private:
    EntryHandler mEntryHandler;
    MatchFinder mMatcher;
};

EDIT:
Here is the very simple source 'C' file I am trying to instrument:
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int functionReturns2();
int testSwitchStatement(int);
short testIfStatement(int arg1, short arg2);

int
main()
{
    static int gStat = 0;
    // we should insert the probe above this line as total is initialized below.
    int total = functionReturns2();
    printf ("functionA returns %d\n", total);
    testSwitchStatement(total);
    printf ("testIfStatement returns %d\n", testIfStatement(total, 1));
    return 0;
}

int
functionReturns2()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    short c;

    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    c = 1;

    if (true) {
        // a clang::DeclStmt can contain multiple clang::Decls
        // per the following line of code. We should not add
        // a probe here as the scope is not next the functinoDecl.
        int a, b, c;
    }

    int total = a + b + (int)c;
    // should return 2
    return total;
}

int
testSwitchStatement(int arg) {
    int total = 0;
    switch (arg) {
    case 1:
        printf("arg is 1\n");
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("arg is 2\n");
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("arg is 3\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("arg is %d\n", arg);
        break;
    }
    return total;
}

short
testIfStatement(int arg1, short arg2)
{
    int a, b, c = 0;
    if (arg1 == 2) {
        printf("arg1 is 2\n");
    } else if (arg2 == 1) {
        printf("arg1 is 1\n");
    } else {
        printf("arg1 is %d\n", arg1);
    }
    return 0;
}

static void
testConstLocals()
{
    const int* foo;
    const int* bar;
    const int* baz;
    const int bat = 0;
    const int bau = 1;
}


The task of finding the last uninitialized local variable declaration in
a function is not well-suited to what
Clang AST matchers
can do.  There is no last operator, for example.  The
forEachDescendant matcher causes multiple match results to be found
inside each function (one for each uninitialized declaration), which are
then passed separately to MatchCallback::run.  Correlating the
resulting callbacks is a straightforward bookkeeping task, but
significant effort for not much gain.
Instead, I think this case calls for direct AST inspection so you have
full control over the filtering.  After using a matcher (if you want) to
find all
FunctionDecl
nodes, navigate to the declarations using:

FunctionDecl::getBody() to get the body
Stmt,

dyn_cast<>
to downcast to
CompoundStmt,

CompoundStmt::body() to get an iterable sequence of Stmt,

dyn_cast<> to downcast each statement to
DeclStmt,

DeclStmt::decls() to get an iterable sequence of
Decl,

dyn_cast<> to downcast each declaration to
VarDecl,
and finally,

VarDecl::hasInit() to check for an initializer.


The iteration will go in source code order, so you can get the textually
last just by remembering the last uninitialized declaration seen during
the iteration.
Regarding source locations:

DeclStmt::getEndLoc() will get the end of a declaration statement.

CompoundStmt::getBeginLoc() will get the opening brace.


The following complete program demonstrates the procedure:
// match-uninit-decl.cc
// Match uninitialized declarations.

#include "clang/AST/DeclCXX.h"                   // clang::CXXRecordDecl
#include "clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchFinder.h"    // clang::ast_matchers::MatchFinder
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"   // CommonOptionsParser
#include "clang/Tooling/CompilationDatabase.h"   // CompilationDatabase
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"               // clang::tooling::ClangTool

#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"            // llvm::cl::OptionCategory

using clang::CXXRecordDecl;
using clang::ast_matchers::MatchFinder;
using clang::dyn_cast;
using clang::tooling::ClangTool;
using clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser;
using clang::tooling::CompilationDatabase;
using clang::tooling::newFrontendActionFactory;

using namespace clang::ast_matchers;


class HandleMatch : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
public:
  virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) override
  {
    // Stringify a source location.
    auto locStr = [&](clang::SourceLocation loc) -> std::string {
      return loc.printToString(*(Result.SourceManager));
    };

    // Stringify a declaration's location.
    auto declLocStr = [&](clang::Decl const *decl) -> std::string {
      return locStr(decl->getLocation());
    };

    llvm::outs() << "match found:\n";

    // Defensively make sure we have a function declaration.
    if (clang::FunctionDecl const *functionDecl =
          Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::FunctionDecl>("func")) {
      llvm::outs() << "  func at " << declLocStr(functionDecl) << "\n";

      // If it has a body (i.e., it is not a prototype), get it.
      if (clang::Stmt const *body = functionDecl->getBody()) {
        llvm::outs() << "    opening brace at " << locStr(body->getBeginLoc()) << "\n";

        // The body should always be a compound statement in C.
        if (auto compound = dyn_cast<clang::CompoundStmt>(body)) {
          // Keep track of the last uninitialized declaration.
          clang::VarDecl const *lastUninitDecl = nullptr;
          clang::DeclStmt const *lastUninitDeclStmt = nullptr;

          // Look at all statements in the body.
          for (clang::Stmt const *stmt : compound->body()) {
            // Filter for declaration statements.
            if (auto declStmt = dyn_cast<clang::DeclStmt>(stmt)) {
              // Iterate over the declarations in that statement.  There
              // can be more than one, e.g., "int x,y;".
              for (clang::Decl const *decl : declStmt->decls()) {
                // Filter for those declaring variables, as opposed to
                // functions, types, etc.
                if (auto varDecl = dyn_cast<clang::VarDecl>(decl)) {
                  // Does it lack an initializer?
                  if (!varDecl->hasInit()) {
                    llvm::outs() << "    uninit decl at " << declLocStr(varDecl) << "\n";
                    lastUninitDecl = varDecl;
                    lastUninitDeclStmt = declStmt;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }

          if (lastUninitDecl) {
            llvm::outs() << "    last uninit decl at " << declLocStr(lastUninitDecl) << "\n";
            llvm::outs() << "      end loc: " << locStr(lastUninitDeclStmt->getEndLoc()) << "\n";
          }
          else {
            llvm::outs() << "    no uninit decls\n";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

static llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory("my-tool options");

int main(int argc, char const **argv) {
  // Boilerplate.
  auto ExpectedParser = CommonOptionsParser::create(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
  if (!ExpectedParser) {
    llvm::errs() << ExpectedParser.takeError();
    return 2;
  }
  CommonOptionsParser& OptionsParser = ExpectedParser.get();
  ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(),
                 OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());

  MatchFinder finder;
  finder.addMatcher(
    // The matcher here just finds function declarations in the main
    // file.  All declaration filtering is done afterward.
    functionDecl(
      isExpansionInMainFile()
    ).bind("func"),

    new HandleMatch
  );
  return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&finder).get());
}

// EOF

Makefile:
# Makefile

# Default target.
all:
.PHONY: all


# ---- Configuration ----
# Source repo directory to optionally use.
LLVM_REPO := $(HOME)/bld/llvm-project-2023-07-14

# If 1, then use the LLVM I built from source.
USE_BUILT_LLVM := 1

# Installation directory from a binary distribution.
# Has five subdirectories: bin include lib libexec share.
ifeq ($(USE_BUILT_LLVM),1)
  CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR = $(LLVM_REPO)/build
else
  CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR = $(HOME)/opt/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04
endif

# ---- llvm-config query results ----
# Program to query the various LLVM configuration options.
LLVM_CONFIG := $(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)/bin/llvm-config

# C++ compiler options to ensure ABI compatibility.
LLVM_CXXFLAGS := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --cxxflags)

# Directory containing the clang library files, both static and dynamic.
LLVM_LIBDIR := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --libdir)

# Other flags needed for linking, whether statically or dynamically.
LLVM_LDFLAGS_AND_SYSTEM_LIBS := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --ldflags --system-libs)


# ---- Compiler options ----
# C++ compiler.
#CXX = g++
CXX = $(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)/bin/clang++

# Compiler options, including preprocessor options.
CXXFLAGS =
CXXFLAGS += -Wall
CXXFLAGS += -Werror

CXXFLAGS += -g

# Get llvm compilation flags.
CXXFLAGS += $(LLVM_CXXFLAGS)

# When using an LLVM I built myself, I need some additional flags.
ifeq ($(USE_BUILT_LLVM),1)
  CXXFLAGS += -I$(LLVM_REPO)/clang/include
  CXXFLAGS += -I$(LLVM_REPO)/build/tools/clang/include
endif

# Linker options.
LDFLAGS =

# Pull in clang+llvm via libclang-cpp.so, which has everything, but is
# only available as a dynamic library.
LDFLAGS += -lclang-cpp

# Needed for llvm::InitLLVM, which is missing from libclang-cpp.so.
LDFLAGS += -lLLVMSupport

# Arrange for the compiled binary to search the libdir for that library.
# Otherwise, one can set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH envvar before running it.
# Note: the -rpath switch does not work on Windows.
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath=$(LLVM_LIBDIR)

# Get the needed -L search path, plus things like -ldl.
LDFLAGS += $(LLVM_LDFLAGS_AND_SYSTEM_LIBS)


# ---- Recipes ----
# Compile a C++ source file.
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<

# Executable.  It needs to be inside a directory because the Clang
# command line parser reads the executable name (via /proc/self/exe,
# not argv[0]) and appends "../lib" to find its headers.
all: bin/match-uninit-decl.exe
bin/match-uninit-decl.exe: match-uninit-decl.o
    @mkdir -p bin
    $(CXX) -g -Wall -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Symlink to let Clang find its headers in the Clang installation
# directory.
all: lib
lib:
    ln -s $(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)/lib

# Quick test.
.PHONY: run
run: bin/match-uninit-decl.exe
    ./bin/match-uninit-decl.exe test.c --

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *.o lib
    rm -rf bin


# EOF

test.c:
// test.c
// Cases for last uninit decl finder.

int f1(void)
{
  int x;
  int y;           // last uninit decl
  //   ^ end of its declaration statement
  int z = 5;

  x = 3;
  y = 4;

  return x+y+z;
}

int f2(void)
{
  // No uninit decls.
  int x2 = 2;
  return x2;
}

int f3(void)
{
  int x, y=7;      // last uninit is 'x'
  //        ^ end of its declaration statement

  x = 2;

  return x+y;
}

int f4(void)
{
  // No uninit decls in this outermost body statement.

  {
    int x;
    x=3;
    return x;
  }
}

// EOF

Output:
$ ./bin/match-uninit-decl.exe test.c --
match found:
  func at $PWD/test.c:4:5
    opening brace at $PWD/test.c:5:1
    uninit decl at $PWD/test.c:6:7
    uninit decl at $PWD/test.c:7:7
    last uninit decl at $PWD/test.c:7:7        <-- 'y'
      end loc: $PWD/test.c:7:8
match found:
  func at $PWD/test.c:17:5
    opening brace at $PWD/test.c:18:1
    no uninit decls
match found:
  func at $PWD/test.c:24:5
    opening brace at $PWD/test.c:25:1
    uninit decl at $PWD/test.c:26:7
    last uninit decl at $PWD/test.c:26:7       <-- 'x'
      end loc: $PWD/test.c:26:13
match found:
  func at $PWD/test.c:34:5
    opening brace at $PWD/test.c:35:1
    no uninit decls


Thank you so much for the excellent answer you provided!  I was able to build on your code to instrument C code (which I appended to my question for clarity).  I had an issue with the testConstLocals() that required a call to 'lastUninitDecl->getEndLoc().getLocWithOffset(4) in line 113 of my source' in order to get the rewriter to insert the probe code lines in the right place.  My code is at https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcf4bcbeec3ad0e9.  This only affected local varDecls with the 'const' prefix and without this, the code would rewite in the middle of the next variable.

Glad it was useful!  I'm not seeing any issue with Decl::getEndLoc() and const locals in my testing or in the testConstLocals() function in your test; if it's misbehaving for you, that could be the basis of a new question.  Regarding the link to code, I'd prefer to stick to interactions here on SO, as that's easier, safer in general, and more likely to be useful to other site readers.
